# How to make an ID atribute of class auto-increment as an object is created by a User in a Form?

Tags: vb.net, auto-increment

How can i do that in VB.NET? Is it in the Sub New() of the class?

I have an exercise where i have multiple classes.

I wanted that the ID of each one(set as Public _ID As Integer), to be auto incremented as the User of the aplication Inserts a new object in the corresponding Form of the Class!

I don't need anything elaborated, I just want the program to that and not the user by hand!

Thank you, and I am newbie to programming by the way!

Comment: An auto increment ID is usually something the DB provides as a unique identifier.  Get rid of the underscore, you dont want to be typing that everytime and in VB it is reserved for the hidden backing field for autp implemented properties

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `Shared` variable in the class to keep track of the next ID to be assigned. The variable would then be used and incremented in the constructor of the class.

Example:

```
Public Class Test
    Private Shared NextID As Integer = 0

    Public ID As Integer
    Public Sub New()
        ID = NextID
        NextID += 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

Making a variable `Shared` means that there is only one value that is shared between any and all instances of the class.

You could also consider making the ID variable a `ReadOnly Property` so it doesn't get changed later unintentionally.